# Excel VBA Assign Index Formula to a variable

Tags: vba

I am trying to set a combination of INDEX and MATCH formula results to a variable instead of set the results to a cell.

The code that I have so far is as below:

```
Dim todayDate as Date
Dim startDate as Date

todayDate = Format(Date, "MM/dd/yyyy")
startDate = "=INDEX([Financial_Calendar.xlsx]Calendar!C2,MATCH(CLng(todayDate.Value),[Financial_Calendar.xlsx]Calendar!C9,0))"
```

The startDate formula will find the todayDate inside the excel file and return the value of the startDate for todayDate row. The startDate value is in Date form.

But now I still did not able to get the value returned.
Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

To start, you need to assign the date that you want to look up to `todayDate` to use in the worksheet function match.
for example, `todayDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value`, if you've stored the date in A1 of the first sheet of your workbook.

Next, if you want to use a worksheet function in VBA you need to specify that:

```
rowNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(arguments)
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Events-WorksheetFunctions-Shapes/using-excel-worksheet-functions-in-visual-basic)

and the same for the index funciton, although it might be cleaner to use the .cells property in VBA directly. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/refer-to-cells-by-using-index-numbers)

hope this helps you get

Comment: I don't want to use the Range or cell to store the value. The data will directly store to the variable as I only want to find the value that match and store it as a varibale not saving the data inside the excel workbook.